# Python hybrid multiprocessing / MPI with shared memory in the same node

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mpi4py

I have a Python application that needs to load the same large
array (~4 GB) and do a perfectly parallel function on 
chunks of this array. The array starts off saved to disk.

I typically run this application on a cluster computer with
something like, say, 10 nodes, each node of which has 8
compute cores and a total RAM of around 32GB.

The easiest approach (which doesn't work) is to do
n=80 mpi4py. The reason it doesn't work is that
each MPI core will load the 4GB map, and this will exhaust
the 32GB of RAM resulting in a `MemoryError`.

An alternative is that `rank=0` is the only process that loads
the 4GB array, and it farms out chunks of the array to the rest
of the MPI cores -- but this approach is slow because of network
bandwidth issues.

The best approach would be if only 1 core in *each node* loads
the 4GB array and this array is made available as shared memory
(through `multiprocessing`?)  for the remaining 7 cores on each
node.

How can I achieve this? How can I have MPI be aware of nodes
and make it coordinate with `multiprocessing`?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 16/06/2020:** starting `python3.8`, there is now a shared memory support in `multiprocessing`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html that can be used to have such per node version of the data.

---

The `multiprocessing` module does not have shared memory.

You could look at `joblib` way to share large numpy arrays, using memory views. You could use [manual memory mapping](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html#manual-management-of-memmaped-input-data) to avoid duplicating the data.

To find a way to only pass the data once on each node, I would go with launching one MPI process per node and then use `joblib` for the remaining computation, as it automatically uses the `memmaping` for large numpy array input.

Comment: While I haven't tried it, this has been pointed to me:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array
as a way to share memory with `multiprocessing`

Comment: This effectively emulate shared memory but it is slower than the memory maps, as it relies on a synchronisation process with proxy function to read and right from it (this not communication efficient). Also, you will not be able to use efficient numpy computations if you need linear algebra.

Comment: `multiprocessing` _does_ have shared memory. Apparently you are mixing this up with `multiprocessing.Manager` which uses proxies to modify objects in a separate server-process. `Manager` has nothing to do with `multiprocessing.Array` or `multiprocessing.Value` which only use _real_ shared memory and no extra manager-process under the hood.

Comment: Indeed, shared memory was added in version 3.8 in october 2019. I will edit my answer to point toward this.

Answer (score 1):

MPI-3 has a shared memory facility for precisely your sort of scenario. And you can use MPI through mpi4py....
Use `MPI_Comm_split_type` to split your communicator into groups that live on a node. Use `MPI_Win_allocate_shared`for a window on the node; specify nonzero size only on one rank. Use `MPI_Win_shared_query` to get pointers to that window.